# LEFT OUTER JOIN not returning NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a pretty simple sample query that I am trying to complete.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da20e/3)

```
SELECT
    month(s.report_date),
    COALESCE(COUNT(*),0)
FROM
    stat_summary s LEFT OUTER JOIN ref_months m on MONTH(s.report_date) = m.month_id
GROUP BY month(s.report_date)
```

My results look like:

[image]

My desired results would be something like:

```
month  | count
----------------
    1  | 0
    2  | 0
    3  | 0
    4  | 0
    5  | 0
    6  | 0
    7  | 0
    8  | 0
    9  | 4
    10 | 9
    11 | 0
    12 | 0
```

Comment: You must then have all month available in `s.report_date`, else they won't appear. An alternative can be to generate a series/range to cover all existing month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the months table as the primary one:

```
SELECT
    m.month_id,
    COALESCE(COUNT(s.report_date),0)
FROM ref_months m 
LEFT JOIN stat_summary s 
    ON MONTH(s.report_date) = m.month_id
GROUP BY m.month_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `LEFT JOIN` table order, and there is no need for `COALESCE`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da20e/14/0)**

```
SELECT
    m.month_id,
    [count] = COUNT(s.report_date)
FROM ref_months m 
LEFT JOIN stat_summary s 
    ON MONTH(s.report_date) = m.month_id
GROUP BY m.month_id;
```

Comment: @etm124 Do you even try answer that you've accepted http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da20e/7/0

Comment: of course I've modified his answer so it works with the correct `count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da20e/12). As already answered, `months` should be the table to be `left join`ed upon. Also, the `count` should be on `adp` column or the `month(s.report_date)` column in `stat_summary` table.

```
SELECT
m.month_id,
COALESCE(COUNT(adp),0)
FROM ref_months m LEFT OUTER JOIN stat_summary s 
on MONTH(s.report_date) = m.month_id
GROUP BY month(s.report_date),m.month_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if the months dont always exist in your ref_months table you can create using the Master db.

```
Select m.Number as m_MonthID
COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) as count
from FROM Master.dbo.spt_Values m
left join stat_summary s 
ON MONTH(s.report_date) = m.Number
where m.name is null
and m.number between 1 and 12
GROUP BY m.Number
```